# SQL Server foreign key reference to 2 other primary keys

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have two tables:
Table1 with composite primary key - PRID, SPRID, STIM and
Table2 with primary key - MTID

I need the SPRID field to reference *either* PRID or MTID.  I have seen examples where this can work if the value you want to put in SPRID is in *both* PRID and MTID but haven't yet seen any where it is only required to be in *either*. I have set cascade update and delete to ON and want this behavior for the finished design.

I have tried creating an intermediate table that is populated with PRID and MTID in a single field via triggers in both tables but it only seems to populate the MTID entries. When I try to enter data in Table 1 (in a view of Table1) I get the following message:

"This row was successfully committed to the database. However, a problem occurred when attempting to retrieve this record from the data back after the commit.  ..."

When I re-query the record disappears. If I switch the FK constraint off I can enter data that complies with the constraints but as soon as I switch the constraint back on the data is deleted.

I can't change the db design as these tables are part of a commercial piece of software that I am trying to integrate with my SQL back end but am open to any suggestions of a suitable work around.

PRID and MTID are of nvarchar type (as is SPRID), both tables are in the same schema but you cannot have a PRID value that is the same as the MTID value.

Comment: Do PRID and MTID share the same domain (i.e. are they both just low integers)? If so, how do you know which one is being referenced if both tables have a corresponding entry?

Comment: You can't do a foreign key that is conditional like that. It violates the whole concept of a foreign key. You can however accomplish something like this. It requires a little more effort though. You would need to have both PRID and MTID as columns and set up a FK for both. Then a third column PRID (that is calculated) which contains ISNULL(PRID, MTID). Then you just need to deal with constraints on those columns to ensure you have one and only one of those two populated.

Comment: If I understand your train of thought do you mean that this calculated third column could be used as the primary key source for SPRID? If so then I how do I get the PRID into Table1 in the first place? I can't leave the SPRID blank as it is part of the composite key and I can't get data into the SPRID field because I can't get the FK key to reference both PRID and MTID?